# HTML Templates in Apache Cordova?

Tags: javascript, apache, visual-studio, cordova, templates

I'm currently developing an app using Apache Cordova via Visual Studio, and a lot of my webpages are very similar - a while ago, I had used Django and found its templates (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/) very useful for these situations.  Does Apache Cordova offer and functionality similar to this?  I was looking into Handlebars.js, but it seems like I cannot easily call an entire HTML page template in the same regard as I could using Django templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova isn't really prescriptive in this regard. I'm currently using [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) in my app ([link](https://github.com/adapt-it/adapt-it-mobile)), but I know that there are others -- [mustache.js](https://mustache.github.io/), [jQuery template](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template), [angularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates). Handlebars just happened to be the one I came across first.